# Assets date issue

Tags: assets

I'm using EE 2.5.5 and Assets 2.1.2
When I upload a file (PDF) to replace an older version I am getting the following error message:

```
Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. 
Please check the server settings.
```

The file then does actually upload but the date and time do not change to show the change. I have tried updating the index but the date does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check the developer console of the browser and see what the server is returning for the last Ajax request?

Comment: Sorry, im not sure where / how to do that!

Comment: Depends on your browser.  In Chrome, right click in the page and choose "Inspect Element".  That'll pop up a frame at the bottom - choose the "console" tab and go through this process.  Let us know what you see in the console tab, preferably copy/pasted.  And please make sure they're all expanded (little arrow to the left of the error).  Thank you!

Comment: Or, if that all fails, you can shoot us an email at support@pixelandtonic.com with CP details so we can take a look ourselves!

Comment: Here you go:`Double-instantiating a context menu on an element garnish-0.1.min.js:18
Double-instantiating a select on an element garnish-0.1.min.js:18
Double-instantiating a context menu on an element garnish-0.1.min.js:18
Double-instantiating a select on an element garnish-0.1.min.js:18
Double-instantiating a context menu on an element garnish-0.1.min.js:18`

Comment: Can you shoot us an email at support@pixelandtonic.com so we can troubleshoot this more efficiently?

Comment: This has been sorted - Andris has noticed an issue in the presnet release of assets

Comment: So, has the fix been released in 2.1.2? That's what I'm running and I'm getting the same response in the console and am unable to overwrite existing files.

Comment: Jpea, no, the fix is in the repository and will be in 2.1.3.

The double-instancing messages are not relevant to this issue. If you mail us at support@pixelandtonic.com, I might be able to hook you up with a patch for your problems :)